# Pandas - combinations

Tags: pandas, combinations

I have a dataframe

```
supper_meal_list = pd.DataFrame({'Meal': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ,16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                                  'Meal_Type': ['Good','Cheat', 'Cheat', 'Good', 'Medium', 'Cheat', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Cheat', 'Medium', 'Medium', 'Good', 
                                  'Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Cheat'],
                                  'Meal_speed': [15, 23, 50, 12, 7, 25, 27, 32, 12, 67, 43, 32, 56, 14, 19, 24, 27, 17, 92, 26]})
```

I want to find the top 10 combinations of meal types (supper_meal_list['Meal_speed']) where the 'Meal_speed' is the fastest or least.

I can get a list of combinations for a 5 day week using the itertools.combinations package.

```
comb = combinations(supper_meal_list['Meal'], 5) 

for i in list(comb):
    print (i)
```

However, what is the best way to then locate the relevant rows in order to sum the meal_speed and use rank()?

An example of my expected output for the first 3 combinations is below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Combo': [[1 ,2 , 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 7],
                   'Week_Meal_speed': [107, 125, 127]})
```

Comment: What is your expected output in this case?

Comment: I have added in an example of the first 3 lines. Obv there are alot more. (p.s. I have taken the second question out)